# Firestore ordering query not working like firebase?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

My firebase model to observe posts was as such:

```
let postReference = Database.database().reference().child("posts")
    let watchedByQuery = postReference.queryOrdered(byChild: "/watchedBy/" + UID!).queryStarting(atValue: "")
```

However, when I try to convert it to Firestore,

```
let postsReference = Firestore.firestore().collection("posts")
        let watchingQuery = postsReference.order(by: "/watchedBy/" + UID!).start(at: [""])
    watchingQuery.addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
        guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else {
            print("Error fetching snapshots: \(error!)")
            return
        }
        snapshot.documentChanges.forEach { diff in
```

I get the error `Invalid field path (/watchedBy/P02bS6QrVE122yjrU7L87X2). Paths must not contain '~', '*', '/', '[', or ']''`

What seems to be the problem? Essentially, the query checks for posts that have the User ID in the watchedBy section. However, the FireStore conversion does not seem to be working.

Comment: `let watchingQuery = postsReference.order(by: "watchedBy.\(UID!)").start(at: [""])`. Is this the correct implementation?

Comment: I changed it to that, and yet the query works but doesn't return anything... for firebase, I had to make it starting at "" because the values could change. Will the same work for firestorm?

Comment: I would suggest implementing your code like this *db.collection("posts").whereField("watchedBy", isEqualTo: UID!)* Also, you may want to avoid adding extra path components as Firebase/Firestore does that like this *let watchedByReference = db.document("posts/watchedBy")*

Comment: @Jay, the first implementation you suggested did not work because the watchedBy is a sub collection that contains all the userID's of the users the post is targeted towards, as 'posts/posID/watchedBy/ user1:true, user2:true..... I made it work as such  `let postsReference = Firestore.firestore().collection("posts")
        let watchingQuery = postsReference.whereField("watchedBy."+(UID!), isGreaterThan:"")`

Comment: That was more of a format for reading a collection. You can obviously continue to add depth to the read to get the specific one you wanted. So it appears it's now working? If so, you may want to add that as an answer to your own question for future readers.

Comment: Excellent. I added a little extra to your answer for future readers and upvoted it. Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, I just added a whereField such that watchedBy/UID existed.

```
let postsReference = Firestore.firestore().collection("posts") 
let watchingQuery = postsReference.whereField("watchedBy."+(UID!), isGreaterThan:"")
```

Edit:

Note the change from

```
"/watchedBy/" + UID!
```

to a properly formatted Firestore child reference of

```
"watchedBy."+(UID!)
```